# Excel 2016 - Reference specific row in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to use Microsoft's fancy new table reference system, using table names, @'s and #'s to reference a specific row in my table. The *only* documentation and examples I can find tell me either how to reference specific columns, or reference the pre-made Headers or Totals rows.

I came across what every source calls "@ or [#This Row]" but I have no idea what that means, and putting the @ before my row name isn't working...

**[removed ascii table, simplified below]**

I can use the old reference system, but all my other formulas use the new one and I want to use it for the sake of uniformity, and just for the simple fact that gosh darn it I should be able to reference rows like this!

**EDIT:** My formulas are in separate tabs than my tables. I can use the new table reference system to reference only pre-defined "special" rows, such as the Totals row. But I have to use the old reference method `'[tab_name]'![XY]` when I want to reference a specific row *other than the fancy Totals row*.

Here is my formula which references the Totals row in the "Groceries" table in a *separate tab* than my formula. As you can see, I can use the `Table_Name[[#Totals],[Column_Name]]` syntax just fine:
  [image: Totals formula]

But I can't figure out how to reference specifically the "Costco" row in that table- Excel automatically uses the old syntax:
  [image: Costco formula]

Here's the table for reference:
[image: table]
Does Excel 2016 *really* not have a way to reference rows in this new system? That seems like a pretty huge oversight in design...

Comment: Is it possible you switched 'columns' and 'rows'?

Answer (score 7):

Use the INDEX() function, where the named table is your input for "array". You then only need to specify the row for a table with one column, or row and column for an n by m table.

You can also specify a field within the table as your array, and then specify just the row number.

For example, if you have a table called "Birthdays" with the columns "Name" and "Birth year":
["Birthdays" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiRi8.png)

The following two syntax options can be used to return the second value under "Birth year":

=INDEX(Birthdays,2,2)

=INDEX(Birthdays[Birth year],2)

Comment: (I too was finding it frustrating that there is not explicit Excel guidance on this)

Answer (score -2):

I think what you're referencing is this:

[image: On-sheet table reference]

`Column C` of my table is using the "@" reference you specified. The "@" symbol is automatically added (or can be added manually) to signal that I want the data from my table that is **from the exact same row I'm on**. In other words, if I'm entering my formula into `Row 3` of my table, and my data lives in `Row 3` of the table, "@" will effectively give me the data from Row @, Column [Name] (or `[@A]` or `[@B]` in my example).

---

If you're entering a formula *outside* the table and at least two columns away, your formula would look like this (*note: my new formula is three columns away from my table*):

[image]

The name of your table is added to the reference similar to the way a sheet name would be added when entering a formula on a different sheet. Think of it as the formula's way of saying, *I live in/on **MyTable***. Then just as above, the data location is referenced with the "@" symbol.

The key to this is using data from the table that is in the same row as the formula you are entering (e.g. your formula must use data in `Row 3` of the table if your formula is entered into `Row 3`; otherwise the "@" reference doesn't work).

Comment: Please see my edit. My formulas are in a separate tab than the table they reference.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the way a table is setup to work. Columns can be considered *fields* while rows can be *records*. Each *record* likely has a value for each *field*, and *records* can continuously be added while *fields* generally remain static. Excel is not a database, however, and it can't be expected to perform flawlessly like one (which is kind of what you're wanting, to reference a row by a "key"; if Excel did that, it'd be a major memory suck). That being said, yes, Excel can handle your request using a lookup. Try `=INDEX(Groceries,MATCH("Costco",Groceries[Store],0),2)`.

Comment: Well Excel does seem do this kind of thing, but only with certain "special item identifiers" like the Totals and Header rows. How much more taxing could it really be to extend this row-referencing functionality to any row? But I suppose that's out of the scope of the question- the answer it appears is "Excel can't do it"...